# requires 'bundle org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable 1.0.0' but it could not be found

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am building an eclipse product, which works perfectly in local. But while exporting the product for higher environment I am getting this error:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
 Software being installed: abc Product Application (AIX) 2.3.1.20130918 (abc.product 2.3.1.20130918)
 Missing requirement: Management Plug-in 1.0.0.201702171527 (abc.management 1.0.0.201702171527) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable 1.0.0' but it could not be found
 Cannot satisfy dependency:

I could see the module but its not able to use it while export.

Could anyone please help me out? I am stuck

Comment: Sorry but this is not very clear. What exactly are you doing when you get this error?

Comment: I am Exporting project via the product file

Comment: So is nattable something you are using? Is the plugin listed in the product file?

Answer (score 0):

If your .product file is based on plug-ins you must list every plugin you require in 'Contents' tab. The 'Add Required' button should add most of the required plugins once you have added your own plugins.

All of the plugins must be available either in the workspace or in the current Target Platform.

If your .product file is based on features all the required plugins must be included in features that you list on the Contents tab.

Comment: Plugin is available in workspace and its refered in the dependencies of the required module also Still its throwing this error.

Comment: That isn't enough you **must** list everything in the .product file as well.